# Find Checkboxes and the State in the Image (Jpg or Png) C#

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, ocr, graph-algorithm

Hi I have a list of scanned images (Survey) which contains check boxes.

I need to find all the checkboxes in the image and I need to find whether the checkbox checked or not.

Please advise me. I prefer some thrid party dlls or open source for image reading in C#.

Thanks

Comment: You need to detect if checkbox on the image is checked or not ?

Comment: Hi Romo, Yes, I need to detect the checkbox on the image is checked or not.

Comment: Usually this type of form processing is performed with 'structured template' approach. Same survey, even though images are not pixel-to-pixel identical, they can be processed with a loosely defined template.  If dpi/stretch is a factor, it will be linearly proportional to some base sample. Detecting at least 2 reliable elements will provide you with the adjustment factor. I think it is easier to achieve than to detect every check mark.  Because check-marks have hand-written data on them, they will not look like perfect squares, complicating detection.  I use a commercial package for surveys.

Comment: Hi Illya Evdokimove, Thanks for the comment. You are right. I am working on the same way you explained here. Let me know the commercial package name, So I can take a look. Thanks

Comment: Patric, I used to work with its developers, and now I am an independent integrator, consultant and user of ABBYY FlexiCapture. More info here: http://www.wisetrend.com/abbyy-flexicapture/

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to check if there is SOMETHING in the checkbox, I wouldn't go for OpenCV in this case as this would be a little over the top when you don't have to recognize patterns. The checkboxes are most probably located at fixed locations on every sheet, so I would simply "cut out" all the locations of a checkbox, calculate its brightness, and compare that to an empty checkbox' brightness. I think that should do the job without any advanced techniques.

Comment: Hi Robert,Thanks for the info. We are not having the predefined places in the image. The place of the checkboxes changed according to the scan dpi and the rotation while scan the image. Is there any solution to find the checkbox square in C#?

Comment: Ok, I assumed that you do have neatly scanned JPG or PNG images that always look the same. If you need to find the checkboxes first, you may probably want to take a look at EmguCV, a .NET wrapper for OpenCV that comes with many demos and examples.

Comment: Ok Robert, Thanks for the info. Let me try with EmguCV.